# Where can I find an ASP.NET control to show rotating ads with navigation buttons?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I'm looking for an ASP.NET control to show a series of ad images (maybe 3-5), that will cycle through the ads (with fading, preferably), and have navigation buttons so the user can jump around. [Here's an example](http://www.microchip.com).

Any recommendations? Free is always nice, but I'm willing to spend to get the job done right. Also, I'm using Sitefinity, so I'll need to be able to integrate with that.

Answer (score 1):

I thought Telerik has the product who have the similar functionality that you're currently wanting to implement :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rotator/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Another demo :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rotator/examples/rotatortypes/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a compete suite of controls from OBout, I think the control you are looking for is the "Show" Control and that one is free.

[OBout download](http://www.obout.com/inc/download.aspx)

Here's an example of the "Show" Control:

[Example](http://www.obout.com/show/show_feat_fadingcustomize.aspx)

P.S. I would try to build this using JavaScript myself but the control from obout looks like it does the Job.